# Running hive script in oozie

Tags: hive, oozie

I am trying to create table from union of two tables. its working well in hive console but giving error while I run it through Oozie.

**query  is:**

```
CREATE TABLE reconcile_table AS
SELECT t1.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM base_table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM incremental_table) t1
JOIN
(SELECT EMPNO, max(modified_date) max_modified FROM
(SELECT * FROM base_table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM incremental_table) t2
GROUP BY EMPNO) s
ON t1.EMPNO = s.EMPNO AND t1.modified_date = s.max_modified;
```

**and error is :**

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./tmp/yarn/1c052ddc-1fff-48d0-8eec-a0581fe1f5e4/hive_2016-04-20_10-25-36_116_4089571356350445156-1
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: file:./tmp/yarn/1c052ddc-1fff-48d0-8eec-a0581fe1f5e4/hive_2016-04-20_10-25-36_116_4089571356350445156-1
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)

Please tell me if you have an idea.

Comment: The issue is because of the `.` in the `./tmp/yarn/1c052ddc`. Please check your `hive-site.xml`. I think you need to fix the property which is containing this. The `hive-site.xml` will be `OOZIE_HOME/conf/action-conf/hive/hive-site.xml`.

Comment: Thanks YoungHobbit.. now its working :)